# Why this .htaccess doesn't work in subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file.

The problem is that it works fine in the root directory, but not in the subdirectories.
Can anyone help me out with this problem?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#index/123/ to index.php?menu=123
RewriteRule ^index2/([^/]+)/?$ /index2.php?menu=$1 [L]

#index.php?menu=123 to index/123/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index2\.php\?menu=([^&]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index2\.php$ http://example.com/index2/%1/? [R=301,L]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

Comment: Does it not work for some sub-directories or all subdirectories? Can you provide some sample URLs that do not work and what you expect to happen

Comment: It doesn't work for all subdirectories.

Comment: In fact, the rule that removes the "index.php" works on all subdirectories, but the other ones don't. A think the problem is in the variables, but I don't understand enough to modify them myself.

Comment: You'll need to expand on what you mean by it not working. I'm assuming you are requesting a url eg example.com/foo/bar and expecting example.com/foo/bar.php to load?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the RewriteBase accordingly to the sub directory?